# SQL Query to show rows that only have one value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have problem in writing SQL in SQL Server. Here is the case, I have three tables named `User`, `Client`, and `UserClient`. Below are the sample of the table content

**CLIENT**

```
idClient     | client
____________________________
1            | Client A
2            | Client B
3            | Client C
```

**USER**

```
idUser       | User
____________________________
1            | User A
2            | User B
3            | User C
```

**USERCLIENT**

```
idUserClient | idUser     | idClient
____________________________________
1            | 1          | 1
2            | 1          | 2
3            | 2          | 1
4            | 2          | 3
5            | 3          | 1
```

I need a query to show user with `idClient = 1` AND only have one client from `USERCLIENT` table. As shown in the sample above, the result of the query should be

```
idUserClient | idUser     | idClient
_________________________________________
5            | 3          | 1
```

Comment: User isnt a good field name to have, its a reserved keyword

Comment: yes, that's just a sample and i'm not using that as the actual table name. thx btw for the info.

Answer (score 1):

BINGO!

```
SELECT * FROM USERCLIENT WHERE iduser IN 
 (SELECT iduser FROM USERCLIENT GROUP BY iduser HAVING COUNT(iduser)=1)
```

Comment: whoop whoop! This answer took me over 100 points!! Thank you who ever upvoted it, drinks are on .. .. that guy over there :D

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me...

```
with cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS idUserClient, 1 AS idUser, 1 AS idClient 
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS idUserClient, 1 AS idUser, 2 AS idClient 
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS idUserClient, 2 AS idUser, 1 AS idClient 
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS idUserClient, 2 AS idUser, 3 AS idClient 
    UNION
    SELECT 5 AS idUserClient, 3 AS idUser, 1 AS idClient 
)
SELECT * FROM cte c1
WHERE 
    idUserClient IN 
    (
        SELECT MIN(c2.idUserClient) FROM cte c2 GROUP BY c2.idUser HAVING COUNT(c2.idUser) = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(idUser, idClient)` is an unique index:

```
SELECT USERCLIENT.idUser
FROM USER
   INNER JOIN USERCLIENT
       ON USER.idUser = USERCLIENT.idUser
WHERE USERCLIENT.idClient = 1
GROUP BY USERCLIENT.idUser
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you mention, you can get the result you are looking for in two ways.

```
select * from userclient where idUser = 3
```

or

```
select * form userClient where idUser = 3 and idClient = 1
```

I'm not sure what you really want, but these two cases produces the result.

What do you got to query with?

Comment: i need to get a user that only have one client from table userclient. how can i do it ? thx.

Comment: Then perhaps Scorpi0s answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

This will show users that are associated with the client `idClient = 1` and only that client:

```
SELECT
  MAX(idUserClient) AS idUserClient,
  idUser,
  MAX(idClient) AS idClient
FROM USERCLIENT
GROUP BY idUser
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
   AND COUNT(CASE idClient WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

The `HAVING` clause checks that a group of rows for a user contains exactly one row and among 'them' there's exactly one row where `idClient = 1`.

Alternatively, SQL Server 2008 would allow you to do something like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY idUser
      ORDER BY CASE idClient WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, idClient
    )
  FROM USERCLIENT
)
SELECT
  idUserClient,
  idUser,
  idClient
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
  AND idClient = 1
```

The CTE ranks the rows in `USERCLIENT` in such a way that if a user is associated with `idClient = 1` and no other client, the corresponding row is ranked as 1, otherwise the row with `idClient = 1` (if such one is present) gets a different rank. Therefore, when selecting from the CTE, you simply need to filter on `rnk = 1 AND idClient = 1`.